# how to use for loop to split dataframe (list in list) and assign new name

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

This is the data I am working with:

```
df = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [5,6,7]]
```

I want to make sure I get a new name for each `df[1]` and `df[2]` etc so that I can use it later in my codes.

I tried using the following code:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df_"{}".format(i) = df[i]
```

Obviously I am getting error for trying to declare dataframe like that.

How best can I achieve this? of splitting list in list into seperate dataframes using for loop?

Note: I am newbie to python hence if I missed anything obvious please help me point that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
dfps = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [5,6,7]]
dic_of_dfs = {}
for i, row in enumerate(dfps):
    dic_of_dfs.update({f"df_{i}":pd.DataFrame(row)})
dic_of_dfs["df_0"]
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this does work for me ... for what I plan to do with the data later :) Appreciate the help!!